# defining an enclosing_namespace - how does this impact clang and g++ (compile times, memory usage, etc)

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

Given the example code segment:

```
namespace project_namespace::my_math
{
    namespace enclosing_namespace = my_math;

    struct sphere {};
    
    struct sphere_stuff {
        using sphere = enclosing_namespace::sphere;
    };
    
    struct line {};
    
    struct line_stuff {
        using line = enclosing_namespace::line;
    } ;
}


int main()
{
    using sphere_stuff = project_namespace::my_math::sphere_stuff;
    sphere_stuff::sphere sphere;

    using line_stuff = project_namespace::my_math::line_stuff;
    line_stuff::line line;
    
    return 0;
}
```

When I look at the above code, I think to myself:

1. Yay, enclosing_namespace/super_namespace, I wish c++ had that!  Did I just figure out how to do this?
2. I wonder if this is a horrible idea?

So my question has two parts:

1. When the clang and g++ compilers encounter this "namespace enclosing_namespace = my_math", how do they handle this (c++17 and c++20)?  In the above segment (if used in a large code base), am I creating a situation where namespaces are copied into namespaces into namespace, etc, a nightmare situation for a compiler?  Or is this trivial for a compiler.
2. Is there some reason why this *really* shouldn't be done (in 2023, c++17 or c++20)?

Edit: Originally the code used "super_namespace" instead of "enclosing_namespace" - some of the comments below referred to this.

Comment: What is the "this" you're talking about? What is a "super namespace"? Also, it's unclear what this has to do with the "construction" of a "compiler". How that code works is determined by the language. The compiler just implements the language.

Comment: Having a using namespace in a header file is just asking for problem. Namespaces exist for a reason, just spell them out explicitly in your code. A little bit of typing now (in main) shouldn't matter too much. In the rest of the code you can embed your implementation in a namespace too

Comment: One of the primary purposes of namespaces is to enable the separation of potentially clashing names.  As you have demonstrated above; it is also possible to dump all the names from one or more namespaces into another.  The big question is why would you would want to do this?

Comment: I'm not really interested in the "You want to add 2+2?  Why do you want to do that?" answers -  I'm interested in, "well if you do that, g++ is actually going to die eventually cause it's making these huge trees are or what not, and your build times for large projects are gonna be crazy." -- I'm looking for factual reasoning, not opinions really.

Comment: @iamacomputer: "*well if you do that*" What is "that"? The only thing you've shown is putting `using namespace` inside of a namespace. Is that it? Is that what you mean by a "super namespace"? It is unclear what thing you're even talking about.

Comment: @NicolBolas the "super_namespace" has "using namespace my_math", my_math is the enclosing namespace of both super_namespace, and as well sphere, sphere_stuff, etc.  By declaring super_namespace in this way, I can reference the super_namespace from within structures, so - I'm providing a mechanism to access the enclosing namespace, without naming it explicitly.  This is very useful in some situations.

Comment: @NicolBolas - but as you can imagine, if I had a project with hundreds of namespaces and thousands of classes, by declaring one namespace like this, did I just go and force the compiler to make a copy some huge tree of information?    If I did this multiple times, is this an exponential problem?  This is what I'm really asking.

Comment: @NicolBolas `super_namespace` is meant to name an immediately enclosing namespace of a class. The word "super" is used in the same sense in which some languages use "super class" to refer to the immediate base class. The idea is to have a shorthand to refer to names that are siblings of the class, even when they are hidden by members of the class. Thus, `using sphere = super_namespace::sphere;` is to be read as "declare member type `sphere` that's a synonym for `sphere` in the immediately enclosing namespace". (Took me a while to figure out, so hopefully it saves others some time).

Comment: If you want to alias a namespace there is simpler syntax for that: `namespace super_namespace = my_math;`. `using namespace` has other, maybe non-obvious, effects on name lookup.

Comment: @iamacomputer: OK, just to be clear, the idea is this. Within some namespace, you want an identifier `I` to mean "this namespace". And you want to implement this by making `I` a child namespace of that namespace with a `using namespace` directive for that namespace. And your question is whether pervasive use of this technique will impact compile times. Is that correct? If so, please edit your question to make it more clear (preferably avoiding terminology like "super namespace" and just spelling out the behavior you're interested in).

Comment: @user17732522 - OMG how did I not know you can do this!!  Amazing!

Comment: @user17732522 Edited question to use user177's syntax

Comment: *did I just go and force the compiler to make a copy some huge tree of information?*  No.

Comment: @Eljay - do you know this definitively?  If so, add it as an answer, preferably with some explanation of how clang or g++ implements this (or both).

Comment: @iamacomputer I still don't understand the question. With the edit now all you are doing is giving another name to `my_math`. You could use `my_math::` everywhere instead as well. It is exactly the same. What in particular is the potential problem you see here?

Comment: Definitively?  No.  A compiler could make a huge copy.  How it is implemented is not defined by the standard.  The compilers I use do not make a huge copy, as per looking at the source code of the compilers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went and asked over on the llvm issues page, although with a more complicated example.

They provided me with a link to an online compiler which generates an AST dump, and also clarified that basically there is just one node inserted per alias.

The example I provided them was:

```
namespace project {
    namespace enclosing_namespace = project;
    
    namespace namespace_1 {
        namespace parent_namespace = project;
        namespace enclosing_namespace = namespace_1;
    
        namespace b {
            namespace parent_namespace = namespace_1;
            namespace enclosing_namespace = b;
            
            struct X {};
            struct Y {
                using Z = enclosing_namespace::X;
            } ;
        }
    }
    
    namespace namespace_2 {
        namespace parent_namespace = project;
        namespace enclosing_namespace = namespace_2;
    
        namespace a {
            namespace parent_namespace = namespace_2;
            namespace enclosing_namespace = a;
    
            struct X {};
            struct Y {
                using Z = enclosing_namespace::X;
            } ;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    project::namespace_1::parent_namespace::namespace_2::a::Y::Z z;

    return 0;
}
```

And the dump looks like this:

```
TranslationUnitDecl
|-NamespaceDecl <line:1:1, line:33:1> line:1:11 project
| |-NamespaceAliasDecl <line:2:5, col:37> col:15 enclosing_namespace
| | `-Namespace 'project'
| |-NamespaceDecl <line:4:5, line:17:5> line:4:15 namespace_1
| | |-NamespaceAliasDecl <line:5:9, col:38> col:19 parent_namespace
| | | `-Namespace 'project'
| | |-NamespaceAliasDecl <line:6:9, col:41> col:19 enclosing_namespace
| | | `-Namespace 'namespace_1'
| | `-NamespaceDecl <line:8:9, line:16:9> line:8:19 b
| |   |-NamespaceAliasDecl <line:9:13, col:42> col:23 parent_namespace
| |   | `-Namespace 'namespace_1'
| |   |-NamespaceAliasDecl <line:10:13, col:45> col:23 enclosing_namespace
| |   | `-Namespace 'b'
| |   |-CXXRecordDecl <line:12:13, col:23> col:20 referenced struct X definition
| |   | |-DefinitionData pass_in_registers empty aggregate standard_layout trivially_copyable pod trivial literal has_constexpr_non_copy_move_ctor can_const_default_init
| |   | | |-DefaultConstructor exists trivial constexpr needs_implicit defaulted_is_constexpr
| |   | | |-CopyConstructor simple trivial has_const_param needs_implicit implicit_has_const_param
| |   | | |-MoveConstructor exists simple trivial needs_implicit
| |   | | |-CopyAssignment simple trivial has_const_param needs_implicit implicit_has_const_param
| |   | | |-MoveAssignment exists simple trivial needs_implicit
| |   | | `-Destructor simple irrelevant trivial needs_implicit
| |   | `-CXXRecordDecl <col:13, col:20> col:20 implicit struct X
| |   `-CXXRecordDecl <line:13:13, line:15:13> line:13:20 struct Y definition
| |     |-DefinitionData pass_in_registers empty aggregate standard_layout trivially_copyable pod trivial literal has_constexpr_non_copy_move_ctor can_const_default_init
| |     | |-DefaultConstructor exists trivial constexpr needs_implicit defaulted_is_constexpr
| |     | |-CopyConstructor simple trivial has_const_param needs_implicit implicit_has_const_param
| |     | |-MoveConstructor exists simple trivial needs_implicit
| |     | |-CopyAssignment simple trivial has_const_param needs_implicit implicit_has_const_param
| |     | |-MoveAssignment exists simple trivial needs_implicit
| |     | `-Destructor simple irrelevant trivial needs_implicit
| |     |-CXXRecordDecl <col:13, col:20> col:20 implicit struct Y
| |     `-TypeAliasDecl <line:14:17, col:48> col:23 Z 'enclosing_namespace::X':'project::namespace_1::b::X'
| |       `-ElaboratedType 'enclosing_namespace::X' sugar
| |         `-RecordType 'project::namespace_1::b::X'
| |           `-CXXRecord 'X'
| `-NamespaceDecl <line:19:5, line:32:5> line:19:15 namespace_2
|   |-NamespaceAliasDecl <line:20:9, col:38> col:19 parent_namespace
|   | `-Namespace 'project'
|   |-NamespaceAliasDecl <line:21:9, col:41> col:19 enclosing_namespace
|   | `-Namespace 'namespace_2'
|   `-NamespaceDecl <line:23:9, line:31:9> line:23:19 a
|     |-NamespaceAliasDecl <line:24:13, col:42> col:23 parent_namespace
|     | `-Namespace 'namespace_2'
|     |-NamespaceAliasDecl <line:25:13, col:45> col:23 enclosing_namespace
|     | `-Namespace 'a'
|     |-CXXRecordDecl <line:27:13, col:23> col:20 referenced struct X definition
|     | |-DefinitionData pass_in_registers empty aggregate standard_layout trivially_copyable pod trivial literal has_constexpr_non_copy_move_ctor can_const_default_init
|     | | |-DefaultConstructor exists trivial constexpr defaulted_is_constexpr
|     | | |-CopyConstructor simple trivial has_const_param implicit_has_const_param
|     | | |-MoveConstructor exists simple trivial
|     | | |-CopyAssignment simple trivial has_const_param needs_implicit implicit_has_const_param
|     | | |-MoveAssignment exists simple trivial needs_implicit
|     | | `-Destructor simple irrelevant trivial needs_implicit
|     | |-CXXRecordDecl <col:13, col:20> col:20 implicit struct X
|     | |-CXXConstructorDecl <col:20> col:20 implicit used constexpr X 'void () noexcept' inline default trivial
|     | | `-CompoundStmt <col:20>
|     | |-CXXConstructorDecl <col:20> col:20 implicit constexpr X 'void (const X &)' inline default trivial noexcept-unevaluated 0xbb9e218
|     | | `-ParmVarDecl <col:20> col:20 'const X &'
|     | `-CXXConstructorDecl <col:20> col:20 implicit constexpr X 'void (X &&)' inline default trivial noexcept-unevaluated 0xbb9e418
|     |   `-ParmVarDecl <col:20> col:20 'X &&'
|     `-CXXRecordDecl <line:28:13, line:30:13> line:28:20 struct Y definition
|       |-DefinitionData pass_in_registers empty aggregate standard_layout trivially_copyable pod trivial literal has_constexpr_non_copy_move_ctor can_const_default_init
|       | |-DefaultConstructor exists trivial constexpr needs_implicit defaulted_is_constexpr
|       | |-CopyConstructor simple trivial has_const_param needs_implicit implicit_has_const_param
|       | |-MoveConstructor exists simple trivial needs_implicit
|       | |-CopyAssignment simple trivial has_const_param needs_implicit implicit_has_const_param
|       | |-MoveAssignment exists simple trivial needs_implicit
|       | `-Destructor simple irrelevant trivial needs_implicit
|       |-CXXRecordDecl <col:13, col:20> col:20 implicit struct Y
|       `-TypeAliasDecl <line:29:17, col:48> col:23 referenced Z 'enclosing_namespace::X':'project::namespace_2::a::X'
|         `-ElaboratedType 'enclosing_namespace::X' sugar
|           `-RecordType 'project::namespace_2::a::X'
|             `-CXXRecord 'X'
`-FunctionDecl <line:35:1, line:40:1> line:35:5 main 'int ()'
  `-CompoundStmt <line:36:1, line:40:1>
    |-DeclStmt <line:37:5, col:67>
    | `-VarDecl <col:5, col:66> col:66 z 'project::namespace_1::parent_namespace::namespace_2::a::Y::Z':'project::namespace_2::a::X' callinit
    |   `-CXXConstructExpr <col:66> 'project::namespace_1::parent_namespace::namespace_2::a::Y::Z':'project::namespace_2::a::X' 'void () noexcept'
    `-ReturnStmt <line:39:5, col:12>
      `-IntegerLiteral <col:12> 'int' 0
```

You can also play with the online compiler here:
https://godbolt.org/z/G4beW7YnP

So it seems that creating these namespace aliases is almost free.